# JS alert when n objects are placed in container

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, max, alert

My Javascript is pretty basic and I'm hoping someone can put me on the right path. I'm only building a prototype, so basic is better. (I'm not looking to use jQuery in this project)

**Question:**
I have some drag and drop functionality and I want to create a warning when too many objects are dragged into the container.

I don't want the container itself to be limited with max objects, I want to create some tool-tips for the following examples.

**Example 1 (need more):**

```
// alert "I recommend two more objects"
<div id="container">
  <div id="obj_1" class="drag"></div>
  <div id="obj_2" class="drag"></div>
</div>
```

**Example 2 (need less):**

```
// alert "Warning: 4 objects is a full list"
<div id="container">
  <div id="obj_1" class="drag"></div>
  <div id="obj_2" class="drag"></div>
  <div id="obj_3" class="drag"></div>
  <div id="obj_4" class="drag"></div>
  <div id="obj_5" class="drag"></div>
</div>
```

EDIT:

Example code from library I'm using. Can I use this?

```
rd.event.dropped = function () {
        // message text
        var msg;
        // if the DIV element was placed on allowed cell then 
        if (rd.td.target.className.indexOf(rd.mark.exception[rd.obj.id]) !== -1) {
            // make it a unmovable
            rd.enableDrag(false, rd.obj);
            // increase counter
            num++;
            // prepare and display message
            if (num < 6) {
                msg = 'Number of successfully placed elements: ' + num;
            }
            else {
                msg = 'Well done!';
            }
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = msg;
        }
    };
```

Comment: So where is the code?

Comment: I'm asking to be put in the right direction. Here is some pseudocode:
if n objects < 4 alert("I recommend n more objects") else alert("Warning: 4 objects is a full list"); 

err and ==4 alert("perfect")

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to do this with jquery then you are going to have to write a lot of custom code. What I would do is make my code responsible for handling the drag emit a dropped event (jquery does this with their draggable stuff). Then another piece of code can subscribe to that count if there are too many or too little by your standards.

I edited someone else's jsFiddle drag code with a placeholder for where to put the emit. You can use that as an example. Your use case is going to require a bit more work. Emit code could look like this:

```
init_drag(this, function() {
   // Count the number of object in div
});
```